# Bridge in a multigraph

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, multigraphs

According to Wikipedia:

> [...] a bridge in an undirected graph is an edge whose deletion increases the number of connected components. Equivalently, an edge is a bridge if and only if it is not contained in any cycle.

Suppose I have a multigraph $G = (V,E)$ with two vertices $u,v \in V$ with $k$ edges between them, such that if the $k$ edges are deleted, the the number of connected components of $G$ increases.

Is there a name for the $k$ edges that has been used in the literature?

(I would think the best name would be "multi-bridge".)